# Update an input field based on other input fields

Tags: angular, input

I am trying to create an example based on my requirement.

I have 3 input fields of which 2 are independent and third input field is dependent on other 2 input fields.

The third input field can also take custom input from user or compute based on 2 independent fields.

Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrzgcx?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html) to example I created.

My HTML is

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>A</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="" [(value)]="a"
        (change)="formatedText($event)" (click)="$event.target.select()">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>B</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="" [(value)]="b"
        (change)="formatedText($event)" (click)="$event.target.select()">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>(C=A+B) or (Any Number)</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="" [(value)]="c"
        (change)="compute($event)" (click)="$event.target.select()">
</mat-form-field>
```

and my typescript code is

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic Inputs
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;

  constructor(){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.a = "0";
    this.b = "0";
  }

  formatedText(event){
    event.target.value = event.target.value.split(":")[0] + " is the value";
  }

  compute(event){
    console.log(this.a,this.b);
    this.c = String(Number(this.a.split(":")[0]) + Number(this.b.split(":")[0]) ) + " is the value";
  }
}
```

[image: Example UI]

As mentioned before, A and B input fields take value and display as formatted text. C value is computed from A and B and displayed as formatted text. If user overrides the value C, user input should be considered.

Here are fields with formatted text

[image: Input fields with formatted text]

I am having trouble updating C field. How to implement, auto computing C else overriding C?

In `formatedText()`, I was expecting to set corresponding value (i.e `a` and `b`) to new input on changing.

**Note**: This is not my exact requirement, so there might be some framing mistake in question. But the idea is to update a field which takes input from 2 other fields which require some kind of processing or directly take user input.

*I am new to angular and I would be happy if anyone points better practices to code in angular*

**My Solution**

In HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>A</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="" [value]="a"
        (change)="formatedText($event, 'a')" (click)="$event.target.select()">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>B</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="" [value]="b"
        (change)="formatedText($event, 'b')" (click)="$event.target.select()">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>(C=A+B) or (Any Number)</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="" [value]="c"
        (change)="formatedText($event, 'c')" (click)="$event.target.select()">
</mat-form-field>
```

In typescript

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;

  constructor(){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.a = "0";
    this.b = "0";
  }

  formatedText(event, type: string){
    switch(type){
      case 'a':
        this.a = event.target.value.split(":")[0] + ": is the value";
        this.c = this.compute(this.a, this.b);
        break;
      case 'b':
        this.b = event.target.value.split(":")[0] + ": is the value";
        this.c = this.compute(this.a, this.b);
        break;
      case 'c':
        this.c = event.target.value.split(":")[0] + ": is the value";
    }
  }

  compute(a: string,b: string){
    return String(Number(this.a.split(":")[0]) + Number(this.b.split(":")[0]) ) + ": is the value";
  }
}
```

I am able to achieve what I want ([live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrzgcx)), but is this proper way to do in angular.

[image]

Comment: Put the code in the question

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrzgcx?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html .. I added in question maybe its not noticeable

Comment: Stackoverflow wants the code in the question, not third party sites since code on 3rd party sites can disappear while the question remains.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello , I just realized I edited my question code link, in case I didn't add the code, I might have lost code related to understanding my question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ngModel with getter and setter

```
<input [(ngModel)]="superField" />
```

In your typescript create getter and setter for this

```
get superField() {
  if (this._userInput) {
    return this._userInput;
  } else {
    const calculated = this.calculateSomething();
    return calculated ? calculated : '';
  }
}

set superField(userInput) {
  this._userInput = userInput;
}
```

You can check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vytmyb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)